# Cannot do anything on SSD. It keeps coming back to some kind of "Restore point"

Tags: windows-10, ssd, format, read-only, deep-freeze

Yesterday (Monday) I returned to work and strangely my PC was inside the BIOS (I left it on on Friday when leaving). I continued using it normally without giving it more notice, but it turns out that there was a time when I had to restart, and when loading again, everything was like at the beginning of the morning. Just to check, I tried to uninstall some programs and delete some files, and when restarting, everything was still there.

After a few more tests. I tried to transfer files to another hard drive, as a previous step to reinstall Windows, since the solutions I tried did not work, and after several blue screens, I managed to pass the files and restarted the PC with a Windows 10 Bootable USB .

I install Windows normally, the computer restarts and surprise!, everything remains the same as Monday morning.

After that, I tried to clean the disk with DISKPART, Hirens Boot Utilities and other similar tools and the disk always returns to the same point. Sometimes this processes fails, and sometimes it tells me that everything went OK, but the result was always the same

I am really lost with this problem, the disk does not appear as "Read Only" nor does it show any indication of failure. It is an M2 SSD "Kingston SSDNow A1000 960GB", bought at the beginning of June and had not given me any problems.

Anyone know any way to erase the hard drive completely or a reason why this happens?

Maybe it is a hardware defect, but I would like to try everything before processing the warranty. Besides that I would not like to send this hard drive anywhere, since the OS has no password, and may contain sensitive data.

Comment: Check *Control Panel > Programs > Turn Windows Features On or Off*, if you have  “Windows Sandbox” installed.

Comment: You should talk to your IT Administrator for more information.  Sounds like your enterprise setup is to blame.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm the IT Administrator lol. I'm trying everything but i can't find any solution. I don't care about the data left in the SSD, Now i'm just trying to delete it before processing the warrating because it doesn't looks like a OS problem.

Comment: @harrymc i just checked it. It's disabled. :(

Comment: I really think you do a hardware check (or have your company do a hardware check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the
[Kingston SSD Manager](https://www.kingston.com/us/support/technical/ssdmanager).

This utility can help with the following useful operations:

> - Monitor drive health, status, and disk usage
> - View and export detailed drive health and status reports
> - Update drive firmware
> - Securely erase data

The information this utility can make available may help to diagnose the
problem, and it may also be able to erase the disk.

If the Kingston utility cannot help with the disk, then the disk is dead
or seriously dying.

Comment: I suggested the very same thing earlier

Comment: @John: I don't see it.

Comment: My answer was voted down and deleted

Comment: @John: The poster was surely already thinking what you had said but was asking what to do. Your answer was too general and didn't point out any specific actions that he could do. (I didn't downvote it.)

Comment: @John I didn't see it sorry, i just came back to work. I already tried Kingston SSD Manager but it told me that everything was ok. Anyway the system keeps crashing randomly so i will install Windows on another disk and i'll do the checks from there. Thank you everyone. As I said, i don't really care about losing data, in fact, that's just what i want right now, but i'm just curious about this problem..

Comment: Did secure erase succeed? If not, then the disk is dead.

Comment: I'll give it a try, but I have to finish some tasks first. I'll update you in the next few hours

Comment: @harrymc I tried Kingston SSD Manager. I have another SATA Kingston SSD (In which i have the new Windows install) so i can see both disks with KSM. In the problematic disk options, i can't even see the "Security" tab (I see it in the other disk options) so i cant to a "Secure erase". I checked all the disk sectors with EaseUS Parition Master too and everything looks fine. I'm so lost

Comment: Not all products do the same operations with the same results. I would say that this disk should be retired.

Comment: @harrymc Yes, definetly. I'll keep trying to erase my data, or at least corrupt the Windows installation somehow so it doesn't starts and then send it back to our provider. Thank you all. If I find a solution I'll post it here, for the curious people ;)

Comment: Even if someone uses this disk for booting, it will not be activated on another computer with other hardware.